# Account Prevalidation Doesn't Trigger For Lead Qualification Event

Tags: dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2015

I have a plugin that fires on Pre-Validation for Account that works fine in all instances I can find, except when a Lead is being qualified.  It is creating the account, via the OOB process, but the Account's pre-validation event is not being triggered.

Is there some other way to capture this event?  The Pre-Operation works, but I want to perform the work outside of the transaction, not inside...

Comment: How about a plugin registered on plugin message "QualifyLead" and see if that works with what you are trying to do?

Comment: Would you consider it a Bug in CRM that the Pre-Validation event doesn't fire @dynamicallyCRM?

Comment: I did just try to re-create it and was able to, pre-validation plugin was ignored by CRM, not sure if it is a defect or an intended behavior, don't have a 2011 or 2013 environment handy to rule out the possibility of an issue introduced with 2015.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably not a bug but "undocumented" functionality.

I'm fairly certain that the `QualifyLeadRequest` message handles the security check to create accounts, contacts, and opportunities so there is no need for a Pre-Val operation when creating the records - if the user didn't have permission to create the records the `QualifyLeadRequest` request would have failed.

That said, even if it did fire the pre-val plugin you would still be in the transaction because the transaction starts before the `QualifyLeadRequest` pre-op and commits after the `QualifyLeadRequest` post-op (therfore, everything that happens between those - including creating the account - is in the transaction.)

Thus, in this case there would be no difference between stage 10 (pre-validation) and stage 20 (pre-operation.)

Comment: You're right about the transaction issue... I'm still not buying why the prevarication event isn't getting fired though...

Comment: I agree it should be documented.